# Password similarity

Tags: security, unix, password

I wanted to change my password on a unix machine. I did a normal "passwd" and typed in my old and my new password.

Then the machine came back to me with the following message:

```
BAD PASSWORD: is too similar to the old one
```

That got me thinking... Does that mean, the machine has my password in clear text somewhere? Otherwise it should not be able to compare the old and the new password, right? Or is there a hash function, that enables that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so I followed the suggestion of [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) and went and looked at the code of [pam_cracklib.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/pam/pam-9/pam/modules/pam_cracklib/pam_cracklib.c) and it seems as if pam_cracklib gets the old (aka current) password from the PAM via a function call (that I deem totally ok, as I just entered that current password to authenticate) and then performs a similarity analysis (distance function) between that old password and the new one I just entered.

But it does not do this analysis for all old passwords in its history. That would not be possible, cause they are only stored as hashes. For them there can only be a check if they are the same.
So everything seems to be in order, just like I expected, but now I do understand why it is... thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Your old passwords are not stored in plain text.

Instead, your old password *hashes* are stored in `/etc/security/opasswd` by PAM. It then makes the comparison when you go to change your password, based on what has been specified in the PAM configuration.

An example PAM config:

```
password required pam_unix.so sha512 remember=12 use_authtok
```

Here, `remember` causes it to remember 12 previous passwords.

For further detail, see [Linux Password Security with pam_cracklib](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html).

Comment: Mhm... well it definitely is not a password I ever used before... So it has to check for character changes to an old password. But if all that is saved is a hash of that password, how does it accomplish the comparison then? Isn't one the main functions of cryptographically secure hashes to not allow a comparison between to different clear texts?

Comment: You got me there. I think you'd have to read the source code to answer that one for sure.

Comment: I would expect that it makes variations on the *new* password and if any of the hashes of these variations matches the hash of an old password, it's too similar.  That way, only hashes are stored.  Of course, I haven't checked this in the source code either...

Comment: ok, read the code... added an answer about my findings. +1 for helping me find the answer ;-) thx.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems can store/compute entropy (password complexity) and compare them, I don't know if it's the case of PAM.