# BAD PASSWORD: The password is too similar to the old one using Completely different Password

Tags: rhel7, password-reset

I am running RHEL 7 and not matter what password I enter I get BAD PASSWORD: The password is too similar to the old one using

My current password is something similar to PasswordAABCCD1!

It has expired, when I try to log in now, no matter what I enter I get:

BAD PASSWORD: The password is too similar to the old one using

I have tried Completely different Password all sorts of combination of case and numbers and special characters.

I did not set this server up and not really familiar with RHEL 7

Is there anything else I can try?

I will try to reset the root password using the following method, if someone can look over the article and tell if that should work.

Once I have reset the root password and logged in when should I look for the password policy?

What setting could be causing this?

https://linuxconfig.org/recover-a-forgotten-root-password-on-redhat-7-linux-selinux-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password similarity](https://serverfault.com/questions/425847/password-similarity)

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the `remember` option from your PAM configuration. It's bad security practice anyway.